# Como passar de um em um elemento no carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou a utilizar o Boostrap com o *carousel* para passar os elementos de um menu que tenho.

Quero que sejam apresentados 4 elementos de cada vez e que **passe um a um** sem se notar o efeito.

Com o código que tenho, o efeito é passarem 4 de cada vez.

Podem ver o efeito aqui no **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39VBM/11/)** e ver o código abaixo.

**JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 10000
});
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
 <div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">texto 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">texto 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">texto 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">texto 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">texto 5</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">texto 6</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">texto 7</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

**Alguém tem outra ideia de como fazer esse efeito?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver o problema apenas com CSS. Me baseei [nesse exemplo](http://www.bootply.com/94444) e [nessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/664577).

A ideia é aproveitar o posicionamento absoluto do *carousel* e reposicioná-lo propositalmente ao tamanho do item que desaparece (no caso de 4 items, 25% do espaço do container).
Aproveitei para corrigir um bug da solução original, na minha versão o *carousel* também exibe uma animação de apenas um item ao clicar na seta para a esquerda:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -25%;
}
.carousel-inner .active.right {
    left: 25%;
}
.carousel-inner .next {
    left: 25%;
}
.carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -25%;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/Dv9FF/)

Comment: Amanhã experimento para ver se funciona, no JSFIddle parece tudo bem, +1

Comment: Perfeito amigo! E se eu quiser 5 e não 4 ?

Comment: Atualize sua lógica `JavaScript` para incluir mais um item e use 20% para as medidas CSS. A lógica aqui é dividir o tamanho do *carousel* pela quantidade de elementos; considerando que o *carousel* não possuí *padding* ou bordas, `100% / 5` = `20%`.